# Can someone please explain in lay-mans terms what cp -arxpf does?

Tags: cp, options

I'm inept at understanding the manual apparently. I read 'sudo cp -arxpf...'

Can someone please explain to an idiot (me) what the -arxpf options do in the copying?

Thanks in advance,

Rob

Comment: explain shell explain it all : https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=cp+-arxpf+from+to (obviously `r` and `p` are redundant with `a`)

Comment: Start with `man cp` and for now just treat `sudo` as meaning _do this without regard to the limitation of my account's permissions_

Comment: That's very handy thank you both! However, I still don't get 'x'...when would you not be on the file system?

Comment: it does not say `stay on the file system` ... read it again